# Hardcode XML Field While Converting from CSV Using Smooks

Tags: wso2-enterprise-integrator, smooks

Hello stack overflow community,

I am using smooks in WSO2 EI 6.2.0 for converting csv to xml. I want to know if its possible to hardcode one of xml fields. For example my csv looks like this:

Name,Age,Gender

John,20,male

Helen,15,female

What I want is an xml looking like this:

```
<root>
  <record id="1">
    <Name>John</Name>
    <Age>20</Age>
    <Gender>male</Gender>
    <Check>true</Check>
  </record>
  <record id="2">
    <Name>Helen</Name>
    <Age>15</Age>
    <Gender>female</Gender>
    <Check>true</Check>
  </record>
</root>
```

But instead I have this as a result:

```
<root>
   <record number="1">
     <Name>John</Name>
     <Age>20</Age>
     <Gender>male</Gender>
   </record>
   <record number="2">
     <Name>Helen</Name>
     <Age>15</Age>
     <Gender>female</Gender>
   </record>
```

Here is my smooks config:

```
 <smooks-resource-list xmlns="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks-1.1.xsd" xmlns:csv="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks/csv-1.2.xsd">
        <resource-config selector="org.xml.sax.driver">
            <resource>org.milyn.csv.CSVReader</resource>
            <param name="fields">Name,Age,Gender</param>
            <param name="rootElementName">root</param>
            <param name="recordElementName">record</param>
            <param name="skipLines">1</param>
        </resource-config>
 </smooks-resource-list>
```

Is it possible to add an additional xml field with a hardcoded value? Also if number can be replaced with id as I have wrote down in the xml above?